# File to import not found or unreadable: node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, core-ui

I am using core `UI version 2.1.1` with `react`.

When I try to run npm start I got this error.

```
(/Users/umairsaleem/Desktop/abc/abc/node_modules/css-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!/Users/umairsaleem/Desktop/abc/abc/node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!/Users/umairsaleem/Desktop/abc/abc/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./src/App.scss)
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions"; // from bootstrap node_modules
^


File to import not found or unreadable: node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions.
      in ......
```

Answer (score 2):

run `npm i -S bootstrap`, you're missing it in your project and it's a dependency. if you have a package.json file there you can try just running `npm install` or if you have a `yarn.lock` file there install yarn and run `yarn`

Comment: do you see a node_modules folder in your project directory?

Comment: solved . actually i was using the monorepo with yarn workspaces. I have to put bootstrap and coreUI package under nohoist flag in my package.json